# How to align label to the right in bootstrap without using css

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am creating form in bootstrap. I need to align label to the right align without adding css. Is there any bootstrap class for do this? Any help please!!

```
<div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `float-*-right` css classes (see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label class="float-md-right" for="title">Title</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Run the code snippet in full screen.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!!